Intersection of a sphere over matrix and subspace
I am an engineer and do not have sufficient math skills to properly define the below.
I have a simple optimisation obejctive over $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C}^{K\times N}$:
$$\underset{\mathbf{X} \in \mathcal{V} }{\mathrm{min}}\,\, \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{X})$$
where $\mathcal{L}()$ has some quadratic terms with trivial to find the Eucledian gradient. The set $\mathcal{V}$ is defined as:

$\|\mathbf{X}\|_\mathrm{F}^2 = 1$

$\mathbf{x}_n \in Span(F)$ where $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbb{C}^{K\times D}, D\ll K$.


where $\mathbf{x}_n$ is th $n$-th columns i.e. each column lies in a very low dimensional sub-space spanned by columns of $\mathbf{F}$ with overall bounded norm.
My question is
Is $\mathcal{V}$ a manifold? How should I go about defining it?
a. If it was a vector, I think it resembles a $D$ dimensional circle at least in K=3, D=2 dimension.
b. I could have seperately defined the manifold as cross product of manifolds for each column, but I have a joint norm constraint.

It seems that after a change of variables, such that $\tilde{X} = \mathbf{UX}$ where $\mathbf{U}$ contains the first $D$ singular values of $\mathbf{F}_\mathrm{v}$ might yield a sphere manifold over matrix of dimension $K \times D$.
